How to remove canvas widget border inside frame widget in Tkinter?
I am prototyping a chatbot UI in tkinter. However, I can't seem to find the reason why the border of my canvas widget (at least I am assuming it is the border), which is defined inside a frame widget is visible and smaller than the frame widget. Please refer to the screenshot for clarification.
Screenshot of UI
My UI class is defined as follows. I have omitted the other methods because they are completely separate from the 'chat_frame' setup.
from tkinter import *

class DocuChatbotUI(Tk):
    """Class for the Documentation Chatbot UI."""
    settings_frame = None
    chat_frame = None
    input_text_frame = None
    send_button_frame = None
    input_text = None
    input_text_entry = None
    send_button = None
    chat_bubbels = []
    chat_canvas = None
    model_label = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initialise_ui()

    def initialise_ui(self):
        """Initialises the UI of the chatbot."""
        self.geometry("1000x600")
        self.title("Documentation Chatbot")
        self.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.columnconfigure(list(range(9)), minsize=100, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(list(range(9)), minsize=60, weight=1)
        self.create_chat_frame()
        self.resizable(False, False)

    def create_chat_frame(self):
        """Creates the chat frame."""
        self.chat_frame = Frame(master=self, bg="#F0F0F0")
        self.chat_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=7, columnspan=7, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
        self.chat_canvas = Canvas(master=self.chat_frame, bg="#F0F0F0")
        self.chat_canvas.grid(sticky="nsew")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chatbot_app = DocuChatbotUI()
    chatbot_app.mainloop()

I also use some of the code from here to create rudimentary chat bubbles Tkinter Chatbot Bubbles. I don't think it is the cause of the problem, as the border of the canvas widget is already visible before creating a single chat bubble.
I have experimented with .pack() and .grid() variants to fit the canvas inside the frame widget but neither seems to solve the problem.

This code can't be run as-written since you haven't provided some of the function definitions. Please see here for info on what makes a good [mre].

Many widgets have both a border and a highlight ring (to show keyboard focus). You can make them both invisible by setting borderwidth and highlightthickness to zero, respectively. Have you tried that?

@JRiggles I deleted the calls to the not defined functions accordingly.

@BryanOakley Thank you! highlightthickness=0 was the parameter that did the job. I will answer the question then myself.

Thanks to @BryanOakley the solution was to set highlightthickness=0 when creating the Canvas object e.g. Canvas(master=self.chat_frame, bg="#F0F0F0", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0).
Most widgets define the highlightthickness parameter (see here Tk Docs) and it defaults to a nonzero value for some of them.
